# How to Submit a Javascript Value in an Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-forms

Simply, how can I do this?

```
<input type="hidden" value="some javascript value" />
```

I have a form whereby when a user clicks on **Add More**, more input fields are added via javascript.

I'm also using javascript-declared values to track and limit the number of fields a user can add.

I need a way for my php code to retrieve these **javascript values**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `append`

```
$('#hidden').val('my Text');
```

input field should be

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden"/>
```

Comment: @DevITper happy to help

Answer (score 0):

From the button you must be calling a javascript to add these fields dynamically. Simply append the code to that function to hand over these values to the field.

```
<input id="myinputfield[]" type="hidden" value="" />
<script>
function addOneMore(){
      var newField = // code to add one more field
      newField.value = newValue; 
}
</script>
```

Will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

the question is a bit vague, but i will give it a go

try adding a name as an array and then you can use get or post

```
<input name="myjavascriptinputs[]" type="hidden" value="some javascript value" />
```

in your php you will be able to use

```
foreach($_GET['myjavascriptinputs'] as $ajavascriptinput)
```